# Why would an auto-synthesized property's ivar remain nil even after the property is set?

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties

I discovered an odd problem.

In this example Xcode 5.0.2 with iOS 7.0 on the "iPhone Retina (4-inch)" simulator something happens that should not be possible.

A property in a UIView subclass has been defined as:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) EAGLContext *context;
```

There is no custom getter or setter. So `_context` ivar should be created.

It seems the ivar exists, but yet when I assign something the ivar remains nil.

```
self.context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES1];

// breakpoint:
// "po [self context]" returns proper object.
// "po _context" returns nil
```

How can this be possible?

To exclude collisions I refactored the property to "context123" but the same result. LLDB debugger will say that _context123 is nil.

My answer to this question will follow immediately. It is an interesting problem which others may find useful to know.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that a subclass has accidentally overridden this property. This causes the creation of a colliding ivar in the subclass, whose value shadows the ivar in the superclass.

Comment: Good catch. I've just lost an hour with a "magically" persistent nil. For added confusion, it appeared possible to copy a valid value back out of the apparently `nil` property.

Comment: @openfrog: What's the best way to fix that while allowing the subclass to use an ivar?